# Is it acceptable to test on 0.01% of the training data?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, svm, model-evaluation

I'm doing a cross-corpus evaluation on text classification with a LinearSVM. I was wondering if it is acceptable to skew the training-testing split more than the usual 80-20% split. Specifically, I have 6,183 texts per class (3 classes total) and 79 texts per class in the testing stage. My training corpus has more texts, so I wanted to leverage the number of texts I have in this particular corpus. For the testing corpus, I do not have enough texts to meet the 20% benchmark.
**Would I be flouting some rules if I were to train using 19629 (6183*3) texts then testing on 237 (79*3)?

Should I downsize the training corpus to meet the 80-20% split?**

Comment: There is a reason that opinion polls usually have more than $73$ people asked questions: the accuracy can be relatively poor with small sample sizes.  So there is nothing fundamentally wrong with only having $0.01\%$ of the data as test data, so long as this results in a test set that is large enough to satisfy your desire for sufficient accuracy in the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pick a small random test, but run this testing multiple times. For instance, suppose that your performance metrics is $g$. You'd split your sample into a training 99.99% and test 0.01% using random sampling. You run 100 such tests, then build a distribution of $g_i$, where $i$ is the train/test attempt.

Also, 273/19260=0.013, i.e. 1.3%